# Multi-Client Server Behaves Strangely

Tags: c#, multithreading, sockets

The below is a code segment. I am trying to handle the upstream and down stream separately. But unfortunately handleUpStream() never occurs after handleDownStream.

If I remove handleDownStream everything turns out to be fine with handleupstream. There is something I am missing in handleDownStream and I don't know what.

```
    public void run()
    {
        while (running)
        {
            if (ClientPool == null)
                continue;
            foreach (Client c in ClientPool)
            {
                NetworkStream networkStream = c.getTcpClient().GetStream();
                handleDownStream(c, networkStream);
                handleUpstream(c, networkStream);
            }
        }
    }

    public void handleDownStream(Client c, NetworkStream networkstream)
    {
        try
        {
            networkstream.Read(bytesFrom, 0, (int)c.getTcpClient().ReceiveBufferSize);
            dataFromClient = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytesFrom);
            Console.WriteLine("Message From: " + c.getClientIp() + " : " + dataFromClient);
            dataFromClient = null;
            bytesFrom = new byte[10025];
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        { 
            // I tried to see if there was some sort of exception here that was a silent killer. 
            Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
            return;
        }
    }

    public void handleUpstream(Client c, NetworkStream networkstream)
    {
        // The below never happens.
        Console.WriteLine("this lol");
        if (c.getTimeSinceLastMessage() > 30000 && c.getPinged())
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Removing Client From Pool, " + c.getClientIp());
            removeClientFromPool(c);
            return;
        }
        if (c.getTimeSinceLastMessage() > 15000 && c.getPinged() == false)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Sending ping to Client, " + c.getClientIp());
            c.switchPinged();
            bytesToSend = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("ping");
            networkstream.Write(bytesToSend, 0, bytesToSend.Length);
            networkstream.Flush();
            bytesToSend = null;
        }
    }
```

Comment: If your code never enters a certain place it means that it halted before that place. Single-step through this code with the debugger to find out where.

Comment: Did you try stepping through to make sure that networkstream.Read isn't somehow holding you up?  Also, might want to check `CanRead` before you read (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.networkstream.read%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well this is embarrassing...

In addition to checking it you can read you need to check if there is data there to read... for those who are new like me or forget to check here is the updated code. It is apparent that if you call networkstream.read() it waits for a message (its syncr with the thread).

Here is the revised working code for those who need to see what happened.

```
public void run()
    {
        while (running)
        {
            if (ClientPool == null)
                continue;
            foreach (Client c in ClientPool)
            {
                NetworkStream networkStream = c.getTcpClient().GetStream();
                if (networkStream.CanRead)
                    handleDownStream(c, networkStream);
                handleUpstream(c, networkStream);
            }
        }
    }

    public void handleDownStream(Client c, NetworkStream networkstream)
    {
        if (networkstream.DataAvailable == false)
            return;

        try
        {
            networkstream.Read(bytesFrom, 0, (int)c.getTcpClient().ReceiveBufferSize);
            dataFromClient = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytesFrom);
            Console.WriteLine("Message From: " + c.getClientIp() + " : " + dataFromClient);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
            return;
        }
    }

    public void handleUpstream(Client c, NetworkStream networkstream)
    {
        if (c.getTimeSinceLastMessage() > 30000 && c.getPinged())
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Removing Client From Pool, " + c.getClientIp());
            removeClientFromPool(c);
            return;
        }
        if (c.getTimeSinceLastMessage() > 15000 && c.getPinged() == false)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Sending ping to Client, " + c.getClientIp());
            c.switchPinged();
            bytesToSend = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("ping");
            networkstream.Write(bytesToSend, 0, bytesToSend.Length);
            networkstream.Flush();
            bytesToSend = null;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Actually, you're just doing it wrong. Please see my answer to your previous question about this project. The above code has addressed your immediate concern regarding the fact that a single client that hasn't sent you anything won't hold up your entire loop, but you _will_ run into other problems with the above approach, including the inability to effectively manage tens of thousands of clients (as you indicated in your other question was a design goal for you).